# Google App Engine using UserProperty to link data

Tags: python, google-app-engine, data-modeling, capitalization

I am writing an application in GAE.  In order to link the currently logged in user to data in my application I have been relying on equality between users.get_current_user() and members.user (see model below).  Where I run into trouble is when the user signs in with an email address using different capitalization than his/her initial login (janeDoe@example.com != janedoe@example.com).  What is the most reliable way to link the current user to application specific data?

```
class members(db.Model):
    firstName=db.StringProperty(verbose_name='First Name',required=True)
    lastName=db.StringProperty(verbose_name='Last Name',required=True)
    user=db.UserProperty()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use the username - call `user.user_id()`, and compare on that. It's guaranteed to remain the same, even if nickname or email address change.

Comment: If I do that, I would need to change the property type to something other than db.UserProperty().

Comment: @user589983 Why? `user_id()` is a method on a User object, which is returned by `UserProperty`.

Answer (score 0):

Always convert username to lowercase and then do operations on it: when storing the first time and on later comparisons.

Comment: I don't know Pyton, but this seems right. Anyhow this problem is language agnostic: you always lowercase email (and usernames in general) before storing or comparing them.